# Не расширяется DIV, в котором DIVы с float:left

Tags: html, css

Всем привет

Вопрос в следующем: В div class=content вставляются дивы с классом txt(float:left). Content должен расширяться, а он не расширяется. Что в CSS ему указать чтобы расширялся по высоте при добавлении контента в него?

```
<style>
.content{
width:1180px;
height:auto;
padding:10px;
background-color:#FFD;
}
.txt{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
}
</style>
<div class="content">
  <div class="txt">TEXT</div>
  <div class="txt">TEXT</div>
  <div class="txt">TEXT</div>
  <div class="txt">TEXT</div>
  ...
  <div class="txt">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.txt{
display: inline-block;
width:100px;
height:50px;
/*float:left;*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в css:

```
.content::after {
    content:'';
    display: table;
    clear: left;
}
/* если учитываете IE8 , то .content:after (одно двоеточие) */
```

Comment: В принципе расширилось =) Но теперь то что выводится дальше в этот див появляется не в конце (там где дивы тхт закончились) =(

Comment: @FrancNet, вы добавляете контент динамически?

Comment: ну да естественно

Comment: я эти TXT сделал inline-block с размерами и убрал float: left

Answer (score 2):

Все банально просто, нужно .content прописать свойство

```
.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:1180px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#FFD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
height: auto;
```